# Azure MVC4 RequireHttps not redirecting to https site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, https

I'm new with Azure and don't really know how it works. I have a local site working with MVC and I'm try to publish it on Azure, everything works fine until I set a `RequireHttps` into controller attribute in this case all I get is `"This page can't be displayed"` and the url is still `http:// 127.0.0.1` instead of `https:// 127.0.0.1`

Is there any thing that I'm missing or need to be configured to make it work. I'm aware that i need to install certificate and other things but I want to get the page redirecting to https first even if it's not configured yet.

Comment: Is it possible that you need to setup the controller to be Web Sites aware (if you are using that product)? The `x-arr-ssl` header is noted here: http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/12/secure-by-default-with-ssl-in-windows.html

Comment: Have you defined a https endpoint in your definition file (csdef)?

Comment: "publish it on Azure" is a bit ambiguous since Azure provides a number of ways to host a website (Azure websites, Web Role, VM). What hosting method are you using?